# Filter XPath list based on values in associated list

Tags: xpath

Given this XML

```
<DiagList>
    <Diag id="1" icd="400"/>
    <Diag id="2" icd="401"/>
    <Diag id="3" icd="402"/>
    <Diag id="4" icd="400"/>
</DiagList>
<ICDList>
    <ICD id="400" description="First one"/>
    <ICD id="401" description="Second one"/>
    <icd id="402" description="Third one"/>
<ICDList>
```

I want to write an Xpath query that will select Diags where the associated ICD's description contains
some text.

So for instance if I specified text of "st" then I should get Diags "1" and "4".  If I specify text of "ir" I should get diags "1", "3", and "4".

I tried

```
/DiagList/Diag[contains(lcase(/ICDList/ICD[@id=/DiagList/Diag/@icd]/@description), 'st')]
```

and variations.

I haven't been able to get it to work.  Seems it doesn't like the nested reference to @icd.

Is this something that is possible?

thanks
ben

Comment: Hm. What if you wrote "one" ? Then you would want 1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: Excellent question, +1. XPath gives us the possibility to write an elegant, single expression that selects the wanted nodes. No funny extension functions or XSLT-only-functions are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
   /*/DiagList
         /*
          [@icd
          =
           /*/ICDList/*
                [contains(@description, $pText)]
                   /@id
          ]
```

where `$pText` must be substituted with the desired string literal.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my ">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pText" select="'ir'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/*/DiagList
         /*
          [@icd
          =
           /*/ICDList/*
                [contains(@description, $pText)]
                   /@id
          ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be mede well-formed):

```
<t>
    <DiagList>
        <Diag id="1" icd="400"/>
        <Diag id="2" icd="401"/>
        <Diag id="3" icd="402"/>
        <Diag id="4" icd="400"/>
    </DiagList>
    <ICDList>
        <ICD id="400" description="First one"/>
        <ICD id="401" description="Second one"/>
        <icd id="402" description="Third one"/>
    </ICDList>
</t>
```

**the wanted nodes are selected and copied to the output**:

```
<Diag id="1" icd="400" />
<Diag id="3" icd="402" />
<Diag id="4" icd="400" />
```

**when we set in the above transformation**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pText" select="'st'"/>
```

**then again the wanted result is produced:**

```
<Diag id="1" icd="400" />
<Diag id="4" icd="400" />
```

Comment: How would you do this without copy-of? And template match? How can you print the same values in a single line only using a single xpath expression?

Comment: @FailedDev: I am a little bit confused by your questions: 1. This isn't an XSLT question, but the questions in your comment are about XSLT. 2. Why are you asking about printing values? The question is about *selecting* nodes. 3. Why on a single line only? 4. Do you mean that the result should be on a single line, or the XPath expression should be on a single line? If this refers to the XPath expression, I have written it on multiple lines only for the sake of readability -- it can easily be written on a single line if necessary.

Comment: My question is how would you had the same result, when using another utility, e.g. jquery or php and use xpath to have the same values that you print out at your result.

Comment: @FailedDev: Oh, I see. You would use the XPath API they have. For example in any PL that uses DOM, you'd use the `SelectNodes()` method of the `XmlNode` (or `XmlDocument`) class.

Comment: OK. I just got a -1 for my solution which was printing the exact same results as yours. That's why I am asking.

Comment: @FailedDev: My guess is that there are significant differences between the two solutions. For example mine uses pure XPath 1.0, no XPath 2.0 functions (like `replace()`) and no extension functions (like `dyn:evaluate`). Don't you think this is a significant difference?

Comment: Yes, but it is nevertheless a solution, which of course has the drawbacks you mention. It is not "wrong", of course not elegant but not wrong. In any case thanks for your time.

Comment: @FailedDev: It is my understanding that the -1 you got most probably reflects this difference in quality of the two answers. It can be argued for or against whether such a downvote is "right", of course.

Comment: @FailedDev: One additional issue with your answer is that it uses the `dyn:evaluate()` function from EXSLT. There are very few EXSLT implementations that also implement `dyn:evaluate()`. Even fewer implementations allow EXSLT functions to be used in XPath expressions outside of XSLT. This question wasn't tagged as "xslt", therefore it asks for pure XPath solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I haven't been able to translate this into my environment (Altio front end) But I appreciate the attempt.  I may just have to take a different tact.

Answer (score -1):

What you are missing is the concept of `current()`.  This function references the context node for the entire xpath expression, unlike `.`, which references the current node within the xpath expression.

So you could use:

```
/DiagList/Diag[contains(lcase(/ICDList/ICD[@id=current()/@icd]/@description), 'st')]
```

Comment: @_Mike Sokolov: This is an XPath question, but your answer provides an XSLT-only solution...

Comment: Thanks.  This did not work in my environment (Altio front end).  I may have to just figure something else out on the back end.